blazor wasm works locally but returns 404 when deployed to production after .net 8 migration
I have a blazor wasm client side app recently migrated from .ne6 to 8. App works fine locally but deploying to other env navigates the default notfound page. I have tried multiple solutions after a lot of research but i have not yet found a solution
i recently updated from .net6 to .net8
enter image description here
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
    <Version>1.11.3</Version>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <TrimMode>link</TrimMode>
    <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Blazored.LocalStorage" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Webfonts.v1" Version="1.68.0.3415" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="8.0.8">
      <TreatAsUsed>true</TreatAsUsed>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="8.0.8" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MudBlazor" Version="7.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="8.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SupplierProductRequest.Application\SupplierProductRequest.Application.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SupplierProductRequest.Domain\SupplierProductRequest.Domain.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SupplierProductRequest.Shared\SupplierProductRequest.Shared.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SupplierProductRequest.UI.Shared\SupplierProductRequest.UI.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\css\app.css">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.InjectSharedUI();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorageAsSingleton();
builder.Services.AddMudBlazorSnackbar();
builder.Services.AddMudBlazorResizeListener();
builder.Services.AddMudBlazorResizeObserver();
builder.Services.AddMudBlazorResizeObserverFactory();
builder.Services.AddMudPopoverService();
builder.Services.AddMudServices();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IApiClientService, ApiClientService>(factory: (client) =>
{
    UriBuilder uriBuilder = new(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiEndpoint"));
    client.BaseAddress = uriBuilder.Uri;

    string appName = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string?>("ApplicationName") ?? "Online Product Applications";
    string appVersion = Extensions.Version(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    return new ApiClientService(client, builder.Configuration, appVersion, appName);
});

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount>(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("openid");
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/openid");
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("offline_access");
    options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "roles";
    options.ProviderOptions.Cache.StoreAuthStateInCookie = true;
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppConfiguration>();

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = Constants.DefaultCultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = Constants.DefaultCultureInfo;


await builder.Build().RunAsync();

App.razor
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Error>
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(InternalAppLayout)">
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        @if (context.User.Identity is null || context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
                        {
                            <RedirectToLogin />
                        }
                    </NotAuthorized>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
                <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <SupplierProductRequest.Admin.Pages.NotFound />
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </Error>
        
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

Index.html
<title>Online Product Applications</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-ico href="_content/SupplierProductRequest.UI.Shared/favicon.ico">
    <link href="_content/SupplierProductRequest.UI.Shared/css/custom-loader.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/SupplierProductRequest.UI.Shared/css/font.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <base />
    <script>

    </script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js?v=5" async></script>
    <script src="_content/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/AuthenticationService.js?v=2" async></script>
    <script src="_content/SupplierProductRequest.UI.Shared/js/shared_ui_methods.js?v=5" defer></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js?v=4" defer></script>

</head>
<body style="min-height:600px;">
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!--  <App @rendermode="@RenderMode.WebAssembly" />-->

</body>
</html>


May I know whether you are deploying on Azure App Service or local IIS?

Also, if I use .net6, will I also get a 404 error? I need to rule out whether this problem is related to upgrading to .net8.

Please try installing IIS Url Rewrite on your server and let us know how it goes.

azure and iis deployments return the same result.
i have a version of the app running in production in .net 6

Hi Thompho， do you mind create a brand new sample which can reproduce the issue for me, then I can investigate the issue in my local, thanks for your understanding.

Hi Jason, the solution is too large to recreate, i have created a new wasm app and deployed to the same site and that works, then imported my project to the new solution and that fails

So the problem may be related to the packages you use, can you share your .csproj?

see added code block

Hi Thompho， please try to run your project in local and check the url, then open the production server application. Check the difference between local and server, I mean we have to check the <base href="/" />. And you also can share the screenshots with us (hide your sensitive info).

Usually we may face 404 error due to the wrong baseurl, check it please, thanks~

please see screenshot of both localhost and hosted app

Removing true help get rid of the 404 issue.
